# Java datatype conversions

Tags: java

I am a C++ programmer and I am trying to understand the Java datatypes.

Is there anything wrong with the following:

```
byte:   signed   1 byte
short:  signed   2 bytes
int:    signed   4 bytes
long:   signed   8 bytes
float:           4 bytes
double:          8 bytes
boolean:         ? bytes
char:   unsigned 2 bytes
```

I can convert anything to a bigger or equal in terms of size datatype, with 1 exception, I can convert from char to 4 or 8 byte variables but I can't convert to char from anything else.

**Question:** what kind of rules apply when dealing with conversions involving the char datatype?

Comment: This is already covered here: [Java tutorials. Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and in [Java Specification Language. Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: yes, I checked the official java link but I am confused about the exception with char?

Comment: You haven't made it clear to us what you are actually confused about. You should edit the question and clarify exactly what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to do your failing conversion to char and tell us what's happening that makes you think you can't convert? It's not failing for me.

Comment: This question has a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575327/why-are-there-so-many-types-of-number-in-java-when-long-and-double-work-every-ti/28594679#28594679

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit data type conversion rules are based on numeric ranges. The char data type is the only unsigned integral type, and it cannot represent the negative values that other numeric types can. For example, -1 can be represented as any numeric type except as char, so there can be no implicit conversion into char.

You can always use an explicit type cast though:

```
char c = (char) -1;
```

The range-argument is also why you have an implicit conversion from 64-bit long to the "smaller" 32-bit float.

Comment: +1 for thinking implicit conversions might be involved. I'm so used to making my conversions explicit that it never crossed my mind. :)